# Changing image of ImageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton that is initially set to a drawable resource.  During an Activity, I want to set the image to a bitmap of a user photo.  The picture taking and saving work correctly, but the ImageButton's image does not change.

Here is my code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PATH + "/image.jpg");

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, stream);

Log.d(TAG, bitmap.toString());  //prints out android.graphics.Bitmap@41d772a8
rearEndImageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: why do you need to compress. you can set the bitmap directly

Comment: @Raghunandan I need the image to be high quality.  Anyways, removing that line didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

To do it form sd card you can try with..

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("path_to_file");
ImageButton rearEndImageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.rearEndImageButton);
rearEndImageButton.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

In the activity **onCreate** method assign your button to a variable, and then set a resource or Bitmap which will be decoded from a file using the **BitmapFactory** class.
You can use **File explorer** to select an image from sd card and assign that image path to `BitmapFactory.decodeFile().`

Comment: The code you listed is the same that I have in my question.  I don't want to select from a list, I know the path of the image already.

Comment: Then use correct image path,confirm your file exists there.See similar things works for textView and imageView,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262935/i-want-to-set-an-image-saved-on-sd-card-in-main-layout-background-through-my-app, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725718/android-display-image-from-sd-card